# How to run multiple Java files

Tags: java, compilation

I have 5 .java files in a folder, none have packages, and only one file has a main method.

This is my main class

```
public class Assignment1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayPCB table = new ArrayPCB(6);
```

The following commands execute properly

```
javac *.java
java -cp . Assignment1.java
```

But when I try

```
javac *.java
java Assignment1
```

it does not work, it gives me the following error

```
Assignment1.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
        ArrayPCB table = new ArrayPCB(6);
        ^
  symbol:   class ArrayPCB
  location: class Assignment1
```

But, in my directory, I have all the .class and .java files from every class.

I would just like to know why I need to use -cp and if there is any way to simply run `java Assignment1`

Comment: Include your `.java` files.. or at least tell us whether they depend on each other anyhow.. include the exact message you receive as an error.. cannot find a which symbol? on which line? where shall we look into in order to help you?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/15inout/classpath.html)

Select Start -> Control Panel -> System -> Advanced -> Environment Variables -> System Variables -> CLASSPATH.

If the Classpath variable exists, prepend **.;C:\introcs** to the beginning of the CLASSPATH variable.

If the CLASSPATH variable does not exist, select New. Type CLASSPATH for the variable name and .;C:\introcs for the variable value.

Click OK three times.